# How to change Tabs of a TabLayout from Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

Currently I'm changing Tabs from `NavigationDrawer` but it's not a right way and it takes too long to change tabs from `NavigationDrawer` becuase I'm replacing  Main `Fragment` of Tabs each time and I don't want it. For more

NavigationDrawerAdapter.java

```
public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public Context context;
public MainActivity activity;
public MainTabFragment fragment;
int currentSelectedPostion;
LayoutInflater mInflater;
TextView tv_signup;
SharedPreferences share;
boolean cbc = false;
String fis = "", las = "";
int group_id = 0;
private String[] titles;
private int[] images;
private int[] selectedposition;

public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, int[] selectedposition, boolean cb, String fis, String las) {
    this.context = context;
    this.images = images;
    this.cbc = cb;
    this.fis = fis;
    this.las = las;
    share = context.getSharedPreferences("sharePref", 0);
    group_id = share.getInt("group_id", 0);
    this.selectedposition = selectedposition;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(com.cws.advisorymandi.R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
    }
    LinearLayout ll_contact_us = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(com.cws.advisorymandi.R.id.contact_item);
    RelativeLayout ll_login = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(com.cws.advisorymandi.R.id.signup_item);
    LinearLayout ll_equity = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(com.cws.advisorymandi.R.id.equity_item);
    LinearLayout ll_indices = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(com.cws.advisorymandi.R.id.indices_item);

    if (cbc) {
        tv_signup.setText("Welcome " + fis + " " + las);
        tv_logout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tv_edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    ll_equity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity.getInstance().displayView(3, 0, 0);
        }
    });
    ll_indices.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                 MainActivity.getInstance().displayView(3, 0, 1);
        }
    });
    });
    return convertView;
}

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  public ListView mDrawerList;
NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;
     public static MainActivity getInstance() {
    return sMainActivity;
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.cws.advisorymandi.R.layout.activity_main)
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(com.cws.advisorymandi.R.id.list_slidermenu);
 adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), selectedposition, cb, firstName, lastName);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 */
public int displayView(int position, int position2, int position3) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    first_position = position;
    second_position = position2;
    third_position = position3;
    fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharePref", 0);
            cb = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("ConfirmLogin", false);
            if (cb) {
            } else new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                        fragment = new LoginActivity();
                        changeFragments3();
               }
            }, 150);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            break;
        case 3:
            //    fragment = new MainTabFragment();
          /*  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {*/
            fragment = new MainTabFragment();
                    changeFragments();
               /*}
            }, 150);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);*/
            break;
 }
    return 0;
 }

}
```

`Note: I created each drawer item without using an array or arrayList so onItemClickListener isn't also working in it.`

Comment: Do you want to keep navigation stack for each tab? Then see my q&a here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28367309/retain-getchildfragmentmanager-navigation-stack-after-removing-and-re-adding-fra

Comment: Hey @KonstantinLoginov I need your help now.

Comment: Sure, @Anshul, what's up?

Comment: I improved my code today but didn't update here. http://pastie.org/10632109
 This is how I'm matching current fragment with the fragment which has `TabLayout`. `if` part is working fine for me but else not. So I wanna know how I can use `FragmentByID` according of my code.