# android using getchildFragmentManager to retain fragments when replase and reding

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I have implement an app that has a fragment system exactly like Instagram.
When I select a tab in bottom tab the fragment is replaced in the container.
My problem is when I go to another fragment and get back to this fragment the data is reloading and the fragment recreating.
I have searched and no answer helped me. I see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28694047/4398123) and I think it's correct, but I don't know how to use it and what `FragmentMetaData` is.

This is my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    //set this tablayout to puplic static, so we can access this from othere fragment
    public static TabLayout tabLayout_bottom;

    Fragment fragmentHome = new FragmentHome();
    Fragment fragmentSearch = new FragmentSearch();
    Fragment fragmentLikes = new FragmentLikes();
    Fragment fragmentProfile = new FragmentProfile();

    //use fragment manager to manage fragment
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //set current fragment to FragmentHome when activity start
        this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragmentHome).commit();

        tabLayout_bottom = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs_bottom_home);

        //this code change color of statusbar if current android version is more then lollipop
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        }

        createTabIcons_bottom();

        //this method change the language of hole app. so if user change his device language, the app not changing
        //if you want persian change "en" to "fa"
        String languageToLoad = "en"; // your language
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
    }

    private void createTabIcons_bottom() {
        //this set icon for each tab
        tabLayout_bottom.addTab(tabLayout_bottom.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp));
        tabLayout_bottom.addTab(tabLayout_bottom.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_search_black_24dp));
        tabLayout_bottom.addTab(tabLayout_bottom.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_add_box_black_24dp));
        tabLayout_bottom.addTab(tabLayout_bottom.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp));
        tabLayout_bottom.addTab(tabLayout_bottom.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_person_black_24dp));

        //set color for each icon
        tabLayout_bottom.getTabAt(0).getIcon().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        tabLayout_bottom.getTabAt(1).getIcon().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        tabLayout_bottom.getTabAt(2).getIcon().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        tabLayout_bottom.getTabAt(3).getIcon().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        tabLayout_bottom.getTabAt(4).getIcon().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);


        tabLayout_bottom.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                //set color when tab selected
                int tabIconColor = ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorAccent);
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(tabIconColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);


                if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
                    GotoFragmentHome();
                }
                else if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
                    GotoFragmentSearch();
                }
                else if (tab.getPosition() == 2) {
                    GotoActivityAdd();
                }
                else if (tab.getPosition() == 3) {
                    GotoFragmetnLikes();
                }
                else if (tab.getPosition() == 4) {
                    GotoFragmetnProfile();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                //set color if tab unselect
                int tabIconColor = ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(tabIconColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

    }

    //each method is for a fragment that use when a tab seleted
    //the addToBackStack method hold that fragment in a stack so when back pressed, geting back to last fragment

    public void GotoFragmentHome() {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragmentHome).addToBackStack("home").commit();
    }

    public void GotoFragmentSearch() {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragmentSearch).addToBackStack("search").commit();
    }


    public void GotoActivityAdd() {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityAdd.class));
    }

    public void GotoFragmetnLikes() {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragmentLikes).addToBackStack("likes").commit();
    }

    public void GotoFragmetnProfile() {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragmentProfile).addToBackStack("profile").commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //this says that if no fragment was in stack, so exit app
        if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

        }
        else {
            //exit hole app
            moveTaskToBack(true);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is one of my fragments:

```
public class FragmentSearch extends Fragment {
    private LinearLayout toolbar_search;
    public FragmentSearch() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    View rootView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
         rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

        //select search tab if user back to this fragment
        MainActivity.tabLayout_bottom.getTabAt(1).select();

        //save current tab position in sharedpreferance. so if uer get back from Add Activity, select last tab
        int tabselected=MainActivity.tabLayout_bottom.getSelectedTabPosition();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=getActivity().getSharedPreferences("selectedtab", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putInt("selectedtab",tabselected);
        editor.commit();

        toolbar_search=(LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_in_searchfragment);
        toolbar_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ActivitySearch.class));

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

If somebody help me I'd be grateful. I see the `savedInstanceState` in some answers but that has not worked for me.